# php multidimensional array Q

Tags: php, session, multidimensional-array

Can someone explain what does this line of code mean?

```
$_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$number_of_items]=$_GET["product_id"];
```

IT is PHP. I know the concept of session and I know that it is a multi dimensional array but what is the relation between the statement after '=' and the multi dimensional array.

Comment: I don't believe `=` is ever used as anything other than an assignment operator in PHP.

Comment: ok I know but this value will be assigned to what? To the first array which is ["shopping_cart"] or the second one which is [$number_of_items]??

Comment: Adding `[$number_of_items]` after `$_SESSION["shopping_cart"]` means that the `$_SESSION` array contains a value corresponding to the key `'shopping_cart'` that is also an array. You're creating an entry in that array with key: `$number_of_items`, and value: `$_GET['product_id']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is assigning a value from the URL string to the session. After the array will look something like:

```
Array
(
    [shopping_cart] => Array
        (
            [4] => 12345
        )
)
```

Comment: ok I know but this value will be assigned to what?
To the first array which is ["shopping_cart"] or the second one which is 
[$number_of_items]??

Comment: so that means that the value from the URL will be assigned to the inner array right?

Comment: Yes, but technically it is a series of keys and values. shopping_cart is the key and its value is an array. That array has a key of 4 and a value of 12345.